# ON DUPLICATE KEY update (with multiple where clauses)

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an issue with this query. (mySQL)

I have a primary key (id) and I want to either insert a new value if the conditions don't exist OR update the existing:

```
INSERT into records (name, value, p_id, c_id) 
VALUES ('Store', 'TX', 1188913, 1133) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'TX' WHERE p_id = 6188002 and c_id = 77102
```

So in this case, I would have a record as such that already exists:

```
id = 10235192
name = 'Store'
value = 'AL'
p_id = 6188002
c_id = 77102
```

And I would hope that that record is updated from value = 'AL' to 'TX'

But all I'm seeing is a new record inserted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have specified a `UNIQUE` constraint on compound column for `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work.

```
ALTER TABLE records ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (p_id, c_id)
```

and `WHERE` clause is not needed.

```
INSERT into records (name, value, p_id, c_id) 
VALUES ('Store', 'TX', 1188913, 1133) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 'TX'
```

Comment: Only way around it was adding unique keys, which was my fear.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the answer can be found here.

[Conditional duplicate key updates with MySQL](https://thewebfellas.com/blog/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql)

The actual answer is that `WHERE` clause does not support in MySQL and you need to use `IF` conditions.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO daily_events
(created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at)
VALUES
('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
last_event_id = IF(last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at),     VALUES(last_event_id), last_event_id),
last_event_created_at = IF(last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at), VALUES(last_event_created_at),   last_event_created_at);
```