# Replace/Insert on duplicate key with where clause [mySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically we have the same problem as this question: [ON DUPLICATE KEY update (with multiple where clauses)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764876/on-duplicate-key-update-with-multiple-where-clauses)

But we can't have unique keys for the keys of reference because we need duplicates of both.
Is there a way to do this with one query?

We have a unique identifier, and also need to record date, and increment a value, but also be able to update/insert without making multiple queries.

Comment: So sometimes you want to allow duplicates, but other times you want to update the existing rows instead of making more duplicates? I don't think you can do it in one query, you have to test and then either insert or update.

Comment: No we have an ID and DATE which will always be the same, but there is another row with a counting value which would be updated, the counting value is not used to find the entry though

Comment: Database schema would help

Comment: Basically, SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`='blah' AND `date`='blah'
if empty result set, insert, if not empty (id and date BOTH match) update... Basically there would never be a duplicate where ID and DATE would both be the same, rather only one or the other would be duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me if I'm understanding you incorrectly, but it seems to me that what you want can in fact be done with the `UNIQUE` contraint mentioned in the [question you're referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764876/on-duplicate-key-update-with-multiple-where-clauses).

Are you aware that you can create a `UNIQUE` constraint on more than one column? That is, the combination of the 2 columns is unique, but the columns themselves don't have to be.

In your case, you would use `ALTER TABLE table ADD CONSTRAINT uq_table_id_date UNIQUE (id, date)`.